# Не получается корректно импортировать csv файл

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть csv файл вот такого содержания. Прилагаю несколько первых строк:

```
8923,partner,"",f,,9246,"{'"uid'": null, '"role'": '"partner'", '"email'": '"o1@cttgroup.ru'", '"photo'": null, '"isTest'": false, '"company'": null, '"manager'": null, '"employee'": [], '"fullName'": '"Филиппов Олег'", '"isActive'": true, '"lastName'": '"Филиппов'", '"position'": null, '"username'": '"ofilippov@crs-group.ru'", '"assistant'": null, '"birthDate'": null, '"firstName'": '"Олег'", '"photoFull'": null, '"department'": null, '"patronymic'": '"'", '"workPhones'": ['"+7(903) 111-1111'"], '"contractors'": [], '"managerName'": null, '"assistantName'": null, '"departmentUid'": null, '"internalPhone'": '"'", '"organizations'": [], '"employmentDate'": null}","",Филиппов Олег,,,,"{'"+7(903) 111-1111'"}"

6462,employee,"",f,,6587,"{'"role'": '"employee'", '"email'": '"sdit@samolet.ru'", '"photo'": null, '"isTest'": false, '"company'": null, '"manager'": null, '"employee'": [], '"fullName'": '"SDIT'", '"lastName'": '"'", '"position'": null, '"username'": '"sdit'", '"firstName'": '"'", '"department'": null, '"workPhones'": [], '"contractors'": [], '"internalPhone'": '"'"}","",SDIT,,,,{}

6466,employee,"",f,,6591,"{'"role'": '"employee'", '"email'": '"alhideo@samt.ru'", '"photo'": null, '"isTest'": false, '"company'": null, '"manager'": null, '"employee'": [], '"fullName'": '"alhideo'", '"lastName'": '"'", '"position'": null, '"username'": '"alhideo'", '"firstName'": '"alhideo'", '"department'": null, '"workPhones'": [], '"contractors'": [], '"internalPhone'": '"'"}","",alhideo,,,,{}

16205,partner,"",f,145837,16528,"{'"uid'": null, '"role'": '"partner'", '"email'": '"suev@mail.ru'", '"photo'": null, '"isTest'": false, '"company'": null, '"manager'": null, '"employee'": [{'"id'": 8825, '"owner'": true, '"phone'": '"+7 (911) 111-11-11'", '"modules'": [], '"isActive'": true, '"position'": '"'", '"contractor'": {'"id'": 145837, '"inn'": '"7903202525'", '"kpp'": '"790701001'", '"guid'": '"71cb5e0f-d7ce-11eb-80fe-005056b874f5'", '"name'": '"ГРС ООО'"}, '"modulesIds'": []}], '"fullName'": '"Суев За'", '"isActive'": true, '"lastName'": '"Суев'", '"position'": null, '"username'": '"suev@mail.ru'", '"assistant'": null, '"birthDate'": null, '"firstName'": '"За'", '"photoFull'": null, '"department'": null, '"patronymic'": '"'", '"workPhones'": ['"+7 (911) 111-11-11'"], '"contractors'": [{'"id'": 145837, '"inn'": '"7903202525'", '"kpp'": '"790701001'", '"guid'": '"71cb5e0f-d7ce-11eb-80fe-005056b874f5'", '"name'": '"ГРС ООО'"}], '"managerName'": null, '"assistantName'": null, '"departmentUid'": null, '"internalPhone'": '"'", '"organizations'": [], '"employmentDate'": null}","",Суев За,,,,"{'"+7 (911) 111-11-11'"}"

6468,employee,"",f,,6593,"{'"role'": '"employee'", '"email'": '"scanne@samo.ru'", '"photo'": null, '"isTest'": false, '"company'": null, '"manager'": null, '"employee'": [], '"fullName'": '"Dynamics User'", '"lastName'": '"'", '"position'": null, '"username'": '"crm_test1'", '"firstName'": '"Dynamics User'", '"department'": null, '"workPhones'": [], '"contractors'": [], '"internalPhone'": '"'"}","",Dynamics User,,,,{}
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
df_ls = pd.read_csv("users_profile.csv", sep=",", header=None, on_bad_lines='skip', quotechar='"', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Не получается корректно импортировать.

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Что означает фраза "Не получается корректно импортировать."? Расшифруйте подробнее. С виду параметры правильные, только кодировка какая-то экзотическая. У вас какая ОС? Кодировка обычно `utf-8` или `cp1251`, например.

Comment: Почему `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`? Это латинская кодировка (это синоним latin1, см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1), в ней нет кириллицы.

Comment: В таком виде получается всего один столбец, а мне нужно чтобы столбцами были в т.ч. ключи словаря.

Comment: С другой кодировкой ругается. Методом тыка эта кодировка выдает данные, но только скопом в одном столбце. Система обычная виндовс.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот, как именно выдает данные

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Странно, с таким разделителем не должно быть в один столбец всё. Я даже попробовал прямо из текста прочитать - читает в отдельные колонки. Думаю вы всё же с кодировкой намудрили.

Comment: Ясно. А какая у вас кодировка? Я работаю в colab.

Comment: Я тоже в колаб, просто в переменную текст записал. В какой кодировке лежит конкретно ваш файл можно только гадать. Проще всего будет если вы выложите куда-то ваш файл или его кусок и дадите ссылку.

Comment: Ясно возможно проблема в файле. Он записан в csv в Excel.

Comment: Спасибо вам за наводку поработаю с файлом, возможно вернусь сюда за продолжение реализации.

Comment: Вы пробовали кодировку `cp1251`? Если файл из винды пришёл, то её нужно первым делом пробовать. Хотя там возможна и `utf-16le`, если правильно помню.